# How do I execute a callback function from another function file in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, callback

I have two functions: one which creates the UI with buttons, and another one from which I'd like to execute the same function as pressing the button does.

When I dig into the figure with `get(gcf,'children')` I find the buttons, with a Callback property that looks like this:

```
ans = 
    [function_handle]
    [              1]
    [              1]
    [1x6 double]
```

Now, as far as I understand, with the first array element I should be able to execute the same function as is executed when the button is pressed from the UI, but how do I do that? I tried everything, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the result you got for the button callback, it appears that the callback has been created in the following way (just for example):

```
hButton = uicontrol(...,'Callback',{@button_callback,1,1,[1:6]});
```

where the callback function `button_callback` is defined as follows:

```
function button_callback(hObject,eventdata,a,b,c)
  ...
end
```

Notice that there are [*two extra arguments* in the input argument list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/write-callbacks-using-the-programmatic-workflow.html#brqow8p) for the callback function: `hObject` (the handle of the object invoking the callback) and `eventdata` (a structure of event data).

If you want to invoke the function handle with the 3 additional arguments that should be passed to it (`1`, `1`, and a 1-by-6 array), you need to also pass arguments for the `hObject` and `eventdata` inputs. Here's how calling the function would look (using your variable `ans`):

```
ans{1}(hButton,[],ans{2:end});
```

You first get the function handle from the cell array (`ans{1}`) then [call it using parentheses as you would any other function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/calling-a-function-using-its-handle.html). For `hObject` you can pass the handle to the uicontrol object (or an empty value if it isn't needed), and for `eventdata` you can just pass an empty value. The additional values are then taken from the cell array as a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) (`ans{2:end}`) and each is passed to the function as a separate additional argument.

Comment: Not much left to ask after this answer. :) What got me was the cell arrays.. Never used them before, so didn't realise i should read them differently ({} instead of []) .

Answer (score 1):

You can call it with the () operator, or you can pass it to feval. You'll need to extract it from the cell array first.

```
x; % holds your ans from original question
fcn = x{1}; % Extract from cell array
fcn(); % call with () syntax
feval(fcn); % call with feval() syntax
```

If that doesn't work, please post exact code and error message so we can see what's going wrong.